# How to Save a Raster or Polygon to ArcMap Table of Contents in C#?

Tags: arcmap, raster, c#

Just as the title says, I want to save the Raster to the table of contents.

I have a Raster displaying on the ArcMap IDisplay, but I can't figure out how to save it to the Table of Contents in ArcMap.  The save to TOC will come after a button is pressed in ArcMap.

Looking for code here.  C# of VB.NET will be fine!

Thanks all!

Comment: By "save", do you mean you want to create a raster layer, point it to your data, and add this layer to the TOC?

Comment: yep, you got that right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already have a raster object available in your code:

```
RasterLayer rlayer = new RasterLayerClass();
rlayer.CreateFromRaster(raster);
rlayer.Name = "My new raster Layer";
IMxDocument doc = m_application.Document as IMxDocument;
IMap map = doc.FocusMap;
map.AddLayer(rlayer);
```

m_application is of type IApplication and is a reference to your ArcMap instance.
It works quite similar for any feature class. Just create an object of the corrensping layer type, set the feature class to display and add the layer object to the map:

```
FeatureLayer featLayer = new FeatureLayerClass();
featLayer.FeatureClass = myFeatureClass;
featLayer.Name = "My new feature layer";
IMxDocument doc = m_application.Document as IMxDocument;
doc.FocusMap.AddLayer(featLayer);
```

Comment: I added the code for feature layers.